# Reset Auto Increment (identity) each year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I would like to create a trigger.

For each add (only add), a column will be update like that :

```
ABC-CurrentYear-AutoIncrementCode
```

exemple :

```
ABC-2013-00001
```

or

```
ABC-2013-1
```

`ABC` will never change

Current year could be added with `YEAR(GetDate())`, but for the last part, I've got difficulty: how can I get the last entry number to make last entry + 1?

Second problem :

In 2014, the auto increment counter should be reset to 1, same for 2015 etc...

Comment: I think I would do this with a datetime and a view.

Comment: Do you have a datetime column? And where does ABC come from? Is it static?

Comment: Also, do you expect to upgrade to SQL Server 2012: it's a lot easier with this version

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the new value like this:

```
SELECT 'ABC-' + 
CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(YourColumnName, 'ABC-' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-', '') AS INTEGER)), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(5)), 5)
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumnName LIKE 'ABC-' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +'%'
```

The last part of the string concatenation is particulary complicated:

- RIGHT is used to add leading zeros
- ISNULL is used to reset the counter every year

Answer (score 0):

Using a sample table that looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), someCol NVARCHAR(20), codeCol NVARCHAR(20))
```

Having an id column, some random value column and third column where your code is stored.

Your trigger might look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgInsertMyTable ON myTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(20)
    SELECT @code = 'ABC-' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '-'

    DECLARE @max NVARCHAR(20)
    SELECT @max = codeCol FROM dbo.myTable mts WHERE mts.codeCol LIKE @code + '%'

    ;WITH CTE_UPD AS 
    (
        SELECT REPLICATE('0', 5-LEN(CAST(COALESCE(CAST(RIGHT(@max,5) AS INT),0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ins.ID) AS NVARCHAR(5)))) + CAST(COALESCE(CAST(RIGHT(@max,5) AS INT),0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ins.ID) AS NVARCHAR(5)) AS nextNo, id
        FROM INSERTED ins

    )
    UPDATE mt
    SET mt.CodeCol = @code + nextNo 
    FROM dbo.MyTable mt
    INNER JOIN CTE_UPD ins ON ins.ID = mt.ID

END
```

I know it looks complicated at some places, so I'll try to explain it a bit, but
first - here is a demo that it does works properly:

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92a54/2)**

So, first I setup a desired code prefix in `@code` variable - that's the part without increment.

Second - I search in existing rows in table for maximal value with same prefix - and store it in variable `@max`

Third part is CTE - it's used to find the next increment value.

- From the max value strip only the last 5 characters (RIGHT function)
- convert them to int (CAST) - stripping it from starting zeros
- if @max was NULL - now it's declared 0 (COALESCE)
- add ROW_NUMBER from inserted to it - this is important - you can't just use +1 because you might add more then 1 row at the same time (like in demo). This is the whole reason CTE is needed in the first place.
- cast back to nvarchar
- REPLICATE is used to return the starting zeros in the amount of 5-LEN (new LEN in calculated to add less zeroes when number become 10, 100, 1000)

At the end, just join CTE to table and update with @code + calculated value

I am not sure, if there might be a simpler solution but this one works - and I think covers all the scenarios.

Comment: This isn't safe for concurrency. Overlapping calls in a busy system will generate duplicate numbers, as well as deadlocking issues because of table access and subsequent write in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

But where to use these functions.For Example if Student table as RegNo. requiring this Auto-Year-Increment property.Where should one write this code?Either in a stored procedure or somewhere else.